# Python: Search for a set of words in first column on .csv files in a directory

Tags: python, string, csv, comparison

I am trying to search if the first column in any of the .csv files in a directory has the values as: TPW or KPM1 or KPM2

and if so then i want to write this file name into the file "Outfile_Files.txt".

Still i am unable to search correctly; Please enlighten me.

```
import os
import string

outfile = open("Outfile_Files.txt","w")

for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                words = line.split(",")                                
                if words[0] in "TPW" or "KPM1" or "KPM2":
                    print words[0]
                    outfile.write(filename+ '\n')
                    break;  
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test for set membership you should use

```
if words[0] in {"TPW", "KPM1", "KPM2"}:
```

not

```
if words[0] in "TPW" or "KPM1" or "KPM2":
```

Condition `words[0] in "TPW" or "KPM1" or "KPM2"` always evaluates as `True` in boolean context.

First Python evaluates `words[0] in "TPW"`. If `words[0]` is a substring of `"TPW"` then the whole condition is `True`.
If words[0] is not a substring of "TPW" then Python goes to `"KPM1"` which is not empty string and is always `True` in boolean context.